# Graphing slow counters with prometheus and grafana

Tags: graphing, grafana, prometheus

We graph fast counters with `sum(rate(my_counter_total[1m]))` or with `sum(irate(my_counter_total[20s]))`. Where the second one is preferrable if you can always expect changes within the last couple of seconds.

But how do you graph slow counters where you only have some increments every couple of minutes or even hours? Having values like 0.0013232/s is not very human friendly.

Let's say I want to graph how many users sign up to our service (we expect a couple of signups per hour). What's a reasonable query?

We currently use the following to graph that in grafana:

- Query: `3600 * sum(rate(signup_total[1h]))`
- Step: 3600s
- Resolution: 1/1

[image: Slow counter setup]

Is this reasonable?

I'm still trying to understand how all those parameters play together to draw a graph. Can someone explain how the range selector (`[10m]`), the `rate()` and the `irate()` functions, the `Step` and `Resolution` settings in grafana influence each other?

Comment: I thought `3600 * sum(rate(signup_total[1h]))` is the same  as `sum(increase(signup_total[1h]))`

Comment: The `increase()` function in Prometheus can return unexpected fractional results for slowly changing integer counters such as the number of signups or the number of pageviews. This is due to [extrapolation for rate() and increase()](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746). If you need the correct results, then try `increase()` function from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a correct way to do it. You can also use `increase()` which is syntactic sugar for using `rate()` that way.

> Can someone explain how the range selector

This is only used by Prometheus, and indicates what data to work over.

> the Step and Resolution settings in grafana influence each other?

This is used on the Grafana side, it affects how many time slices it'll request from Prometheus.

These settings do not directly influence each other. However the resolution should work out to be smaller than the range, or you'll be undersampling and miss information.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time putting everything together. For a counter with some increments per minute I would use `sum(increase(my_counter_total[1m]))` to show the rate/m. This works best when setting the step in grafana to 1m and the resolution to 1/1. So every value plotted corresponds to the number of occurences per min.. But when you choose a large time frame (30d), the graph takes ages to load because it requests many 1m steps.

Setting the step to automatic (leaving it empty) works for small timeframes where the value < 1m. If the step gets e.g. 10m the values make no sense anymore.

Comment: Yes, that happens. I'd suggest sticking with `rate()` so that everything is consistently per-second. https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/4257 should improve this.

Comment: The PR you mentioned seems to be exactly the solution for this! For now we'll go for the per second rate I guess...

Answer (score 0):

The `3600 * sum(rate(signup_total[1h]))` can be substituted with `sum(increase(signup_total[1h]))` . The `increase(counter[d])` function returns counter increase on the given lookbehind window `d`. E.g. `increase(signup_total[1h])` returns the number of signups during the last hour.

Note that the returned value from `increase(signup_total[1h])` may be fractional even if `signup_total` contains only integer values. This is because of extrapolation - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for technical details. There are the following solutions for this issue:

- To use [offset modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier): `signup_total - (signup_total offset 1h)`  . This query returns correct results if `signup_total` wasn't reset to zero during the last hour. In this case the `sum(signup_total - (signup_total offset 1h))` is roughly equivalent to `sum(increase(signup_total[1h]))`, but returns more accurate integer results.
- To use [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/). It returns the expected integer results from `increase()` out of the box. See [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) and [this comment](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711) for technical details.