# tracing: how can use distribution for unlimited increasing value

Tags: prometheus, trace, opencensus

I try to implement tracing for my system. I use `OpenCensus` for tracing and `Prometheus` for metric backend. In `OpenCensus`, when defining a view, we will define `Aggregation` function. (i.e: count, last value, distribution ...)

My problem is: I have a metric, for example named `cache_missed` to express total cached miss when querying to caching server. This number definitely will increase overtime (and not have upper limit). I want to track data so when looking into dashboard, I will know there is a day that cache miss happen more often. In other word, I want to view the correlation between cache miss at different timestamp.

I think I can do that by using `distribution` for aggregation function. But I don't sure does it is possible and how can I achieve that. Please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for the [increase](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) in your metric ? Or is your question about having the data aligned on day boundaries ?

Comment: @MichaelDoubez thanks. Look like "increase" is the function I need :D

Comment: I am glad. Be wary of [aliasing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218950/increase-in-prometheus-sometimes-doubles-values-how-to-avoid)